# Do I need to upgrade to the latest version for iOS and Android in order to use Facebook v2.0 API

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that uses Facebook API for user login only and we requires only the three basic user permissions (i.e. user_friends, user_email, user_login).

Since the 1.0 API version is deprecating by 30 April 2015, I have been asked to upgrade the iOS and Android SDKs to the latest. I checked my SDKs.

> iOS SDK v3.21.1
>
> Android SDK v3.7

in the iOS [iOS 3.x upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-3.x), it states that by v3.20, iOS SDK is defaulted to v2.2 of Facebook Graph API. I wonder does that mean I don't need to upgrade the iOS SDK for it to support Facebook Login?

For Android, I can't find relevant information stating whether v3.7 is using graph api v2.0 by default.

I have done the following steps:

[image: Setting > Migration]

I turned this to on.

And I am still seeing this:

[image: Top Affected Apps]

Advice are welcomed! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine on iOS, but need to update your Android SDK. If you don't want to switch to v4.x, you can still use v3.23.1, which should be a completely backwards compatible update for you.